# Undefined index: name when processing a form within a class

Tags: php

I am having an issue when processing form data. When the form is submitted, an object from the `sign_up` class is created and the `$_POST` array is validated within this class. Various 'if' statement checks are then carried out to filter out unwanted chars, if the result does not equal '0', then a message is added to an array, please see an extract below

```
    <?php
    include('super_class.php');

    class Signup_User extends Super_Class {
          protected $errors = array();

     public function processUserInput() {

          if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

                if(0 == preg_match("/\S+/",$name = $_POST['name'])) {
                     $this->errors['name'] = "Please enter your first name.";
          }
```

The form has php code, which execute the following, when a field has not been filled in, etc

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['name'])) { echo $sign_up->getError('name');}?>
```

The `getError` code in the `sign_up` class object.

```
    public function getError($name) {

    if($this->errors[$name]) {
        return $this->errors[$name];
    }
}
```

If I load the form and just press 'submit' all errors print out next to the input fields as intended, however if I enter some text into the name input box for example, I get the following error: `Notice: undefined index name`, and points to the getError function?

I thought I may need to define the `$_POST` array into variables first and then check them, but the result was still the same.

Hope someone can help, I have been going round in circles on this one!!

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation, it worked! I almost had it, lol!

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! You should upvote and 'accept' yi_H's answer as he was first with the right answer

Comment: i beleive I have! I selected 'yes' this post was helpful to both of you, I hope that is what you mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to display an error for the 'name' field, but as it's valid, there's no error, and thus no index in $this->errors for 'name'. Try this instead...

```
public function getError($name) {

    if(isset($this->errors[$name])) {
        return $this->errors[$name];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no error, that key won't be in the array. Write it like this:

```
if(isset($this->errors[$name])) {
```